# How to render a State List on one line?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have 3 files, App.js, Day.js, DayList.js and I'm trying to render the DayList all on one line.

Its set up like this:

App.js

```
state: [
  days: {day1, day2, day3...}
]

render() {
  return(
      <DayList />
   )}
```

DayList.js

```
props.days.map(...
    <Day />...)
```

Instead of App.js rendering it like:

```
Head
Day1
Day2
Day3
```

I would like it to be rendered like:

```
Head
Day1 Day2 Day3
```

But I cant figure it out for some reason...Any help?

Comment: Where is the code for `Day` Component?

Comment: Most likely you are rendering a `<div>` for the day component. This is a block level element and default layout is full width. You can either put `display: inline-block;` as the override for the way it should be displayed or you can use flex or css grid to arrange the days from a parent element

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to "wrap" your `<Day />` components in a container that is displayed with flex-box so that the [layout axis of that container's children are horizontal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_main_axis).

The wrapper could be introduced into the render result of `<DayList />`, to cause this horizontal arrangement of the `<Day/>` child components.

So for example, by adding the following CSS and JSX to your project you could achieve the desired result:

**CSS**

```
.horizontal-layout {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

**DayList.js**

```
render() {

    const props = /* ... from somewhere in your code ... */

    /* 
    Cause the "Day" children of "DayList" to be wrapped in a container styled
    with flex-box that produces a horizontal layout
    */
    return <div className="horizontal-layout">{ props.days.map(() => <Day />)</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a styling job. Give your div className='horizontal-layout' and you can do something like this.

```
.horizontal-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```